# Learning C, segmentation fault

Tags: c

I'm just learning C after learning Java and I'm having a tough time... 
This program is supposed to be a simple command prompt program that takes in a command like "sum 1 2" and adds outputs "3". The program tokenizes the input by space into a 2d array. So the first element will have the command and the following integers will be for arithmetic. As soon as I type "sum 1 2" I get a segmentation fault error and the program crashes.

I set every row in my 2d array to "NULL" so that I could know when to stop iterating through the rows. I looked everywhere and I would like to know if this was an incorrect way of doing it, and if there's a more effective way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define tLength 20
#define tRow 7
char input[tLength];
char tokens[tRow][tLength];
char p[tLength];
char y[tLength];
int counter = 0;

void getTokens(char inp[]) {
    strcpy(y, inp);
        strcpy(p, strtok(y," "));
    strcpy(tokens[counter], p);
        counter = 1;
    while (p!=NULL){
            strcpy(p,strtok(NULL, " "));
        if (counter < tRow) {
            strcpy(tokens[counter], p);
                        counter++;
        }
        else {
            printf("Cannot process more lines");
                        counter = 0;
                        break;
        }
    }
        counter = 0;
}

void commandLine() {
    int count;
    for (count=0;count<tRow;count++){
        strcpy(tokens[count],"NULL");
    }
    printf(">");
    fgets(input, tLength, stdin);
    getTokens(input);

    if (strcmp("quit", tokens[0]) == 0 || strcmp("Quit", tokens[0]) == 0) {
        printf("Bye!");
    }

    else if (strcmp("sum", tokens[0]) == 0 || strcmp("Sum", tokens[0]) == 0) {
        int sum = 0;
        counter = 1;
        while (strcmp("NULL",tokens[counter])!=0) {
            sum += atoi(tokens[counter]);
            counter++;
        }
        counter = 0;
        printf("%d", sum);
    }

    else if (strcmp("prod", tokens[0]) == 0 || strcmp("Prod", tokens[0]) == 0) {
        int temp = 0;
        int prod = 1;
        counter = 1;
        if (atoi(tokens[1]) == 0) {
            printf("%d", 0);
        }
        else {
            while (strcmp("NULL",tokens[counter])!=0) {
                prod *= atoi(tokens[counter]);
                counter++;
            }
        }
        printf("%d", prod);
    }

    else {
        printf("Error, unknown command");
    }
}

void main(void) {
    commandLine();
}
```

Comment: first of all, do `int main (void)` instead

Comment: `strtok(NULL, " ")` become `NULL`. Also `p!=NULL` : `p` never become `NULL`.

Comment: `strtok(NULL, " ")` may return `NULL` and passing it to `strcpy()` invokes *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several tips:

1. global variables when unecessary, are bad
2. use capital letters for macros
3. better initialize variables, than left uninitialized
4. use descriptive variable names ( not, p, y etc )
5. empty string can't be compared to "NULL"
6. POSIX offers strcasecmp which is case insensitive version of strcmp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXINPUTLEN 20
#define MAXTOKENS 7

void getTokens( char* input, char tokenized[][MAXINPUTLEN] )
{
    int counter = 0;
    char* token = strtok( input, " " );

    while( token != NULL )
    {
        if( counter < MAXTOKENS )
        {
            strncpy( tokenized[counter], token, MAXINPUTLEN );
            counter++;
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "Cannot process more lines" );
            counter = 0;
            break;
        }

        token = strtok( NULL, " " );
    }

    counter = 0;
}

void commandLine()
{
    char input[MAXINPUTLEN] = {0};
    printf( ">" );
    fgets( input, MAXINPUTLEN, stdin );
    char tokens[MAXTOKENS][MAXINPUTLEN] = {{0}};
    getTokens( input, tokens );

    if( strcasecmp( "quit", tokens[0] ) == 0 )
    {
        printf( "Bye!" );
    }
    else if( strcasecmp( "sum", tokens[0] ) == 0 )
    {
        int sum = 0;

        for( int i = 1; tokens[i][0] != 0; ++i )
        {
            sum += atoi( tokens[i] );
        }

        printf( "%d", sum );
    }
    else if( strcasecmp( "prod", tokens[0] ) == 0 )
    {
        int prod = 1;

        for( int i = 1; tokens[i][0] != 0; ++i )
        {
            prod *= atoi( tokens[i] );
        }

        printf( "%d", prod );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "Error, unknown command" );
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    commandLine();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in C work differently than in Java. 
In C, arrays are primitive types. You cannot assign `NULL` to an array in C.

In Java, an array is an object reference; you need to create an array object and assign it to the array variable.

In fact, Java arrays are more like C pointers.

Your code makes excessive use of global variables and tries to call `strcpy` on a `NULL` pointer when you reach the last token.

You should use a pointer to capture the return value from `strtok`:

```
/* Returns the number of tokens captured. */
int getTokens(char inp[]) {
    char *p;
    int counter = 0;
    strcpy(y, inp);
    p = strtok(y," ");
    while (p!=NULL){
        if (counter < tRow) {
            strcpy(tokens[counter], p);
            counter++;
        }
        else {
            printf("Cannot process more lines");
            counter = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Note: There may be more errors in the code. I never made it past `getTokens`.

Comment: Couldn't you assign a string value to the char array that says "NULL" though? Also, doesn't the p!=NULL prevent strcpy on NULL?

Comment: An array `char p[20]` can never have the value `p == NULL` which is why I changed it to a pointer.